# displaying scraped data from puppeteer onto a react app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, puppeteer

I have a shopping cart app I developed using React, I have been working on a feature which scrapes data from a grocery store using puppeteer. The problem I am having is that im not sure of how to go about and share the data from my puppeter.js file and implement the data, and display it in my react app.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How are you going to share this data? Are you saving it to some kind of database, or is it just reflecting the data directly on render from the scraped site?

Comment: I am now saving it onto a json file but before I had a variable that stored parsed json value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the data and save it to the local folder in a json format. Then you can use it in your react app. For example

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer")
const fs = require("fs")
async function scrapeData () {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch()
  const [page] = await browser.pages()
  /*
  I dont know how your data is stored or what data you want to get so i cant 
  implement
  getting the data here. Assume that i got it and stored in a variable named 
  'theData'
  */
  fs.writeFile("theData.json", JSON.stringify(theData), () => {
    console.log("The data saved to the file named theData.json")
  })
}
scrapeData()
```

Then you can use `fs.readFile()` method to read and use it in your react app.

Comment: awesome I will definetly try that

Comment: So I Have made the json file but how can i read it from a different file other than the one i used to create the file?

Comment: You need to use `fs.readFile()` method inside the file you want it to use.

Comment: Just wondering is there a way I can run a node script automatically using another file. Say I have a parent file and want to run a file called helloworld.js 5times how can I do that without typing ```node src/helloworld.js```

Comment: instead of typing  `node src/helloworld.js` you can create a function named `helloworld()` inside your code and call it multiple times.

Comment: My code for scrapping tha data is in a file, It would give me errors if I put my Puppeteer code in the same file that imports react. It is also an async await function. Any Idea of how I would be able to export the function? I have tried multiple ways but keeps getting errors.

Comment: I keep getting this error when ever I attempt at exporting anything

Comment: ```Module not found: Can't resolve 'readline' in 'C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\Programming-Projects\Counter App\counter-app\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\node'```